# How include file with my custom class before wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress

How can I include file with my custom class before wordpress plugin for redeclare it?

Comment: Care to explain a little bit more and show us some code (of what you tried so far), does it has to with you trying to use the class or some function within the same file yet you are getting PHP Redeclaration Errors?

Answer (score 0):

I think i know what you mean try doing this with your class, this will avoid class re-declaration.

```
if(!class_exists('Some_Awesome_Plugin')):

    class Some_Awesome_Plugin {

    }

endif;
```